# Testing custom API endpoint with class dependency

Tags: rest-api, unit-tests

Sorry I feel like really stuck here.

I have a plugin introducing a new Rest API controller (`WP_REST_Controller`) with basically a single endpoint which uses a separate class as a client to fetch some data. Let's say:

```
#my_plugin.php

function register_items_routes() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_REST_My_Controller' ) ) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/class-wp-my-controller.php';
    }
    if ( ! class_exists( 'My_Class' ) ) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/class-wp-my-class.php';
    }

    $controller = new WP_REST_My_Controller(new My_Class);
    $controller->register_routes();
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_items_routes' );
```

_

```
#class-wp-my-controller.php

class WP_REST_My_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller {

    protected $client;

    public function __construct( $client ) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
    * Registers the routes.
    */
    public function register_routes() {
        $namespace = 'my/namespace';
        $path      = 'get-items';

        register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $path, [
            array(
                'methods'             => 'GET',
                'callback'            => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' )
            ),
        ] );
    }

    public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
            return true;
    }

    /**
    * Get items from My_Class and return them.
    *
    * @param WP_REST_Request $request The incoming HTTP request.
    *
    * @return WP_REST_Response|WP_Error The response containing the items in JSON, WP_Error in case of error.
    */
    public function get_items( $request ) {

        try {
            $items = $this->client->fetch_some_items();
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            return new WP_Error(
            'some-client-error',
            $e->getMessage()
        );

        // Code to be tested. - Do some stuff with items and return.

        return new WP_REST_Response( $items );
    }
```

How am I supposed to stub the `My_Class` dependency from PhpUnit in order to return a predefined set of items which I could test with?

```
#test-items-api.php

class Test__Items_REST_Endpoint extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        // re-hook the routes here somehow with a mocked client?

    }

    public function test_get_items() {
        $request  = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/my/namespace/get-items' );
        $data = rest_get_server()->dispatch( $request );

        $expected_items = [
                'some_key1' => 'some_value1',
                'some_key2' => 'some_value2',
        ];
    
        $this->assertTrue( count($data['items']) == count($expected_items) );
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't, there is no WP specific solution as it isn't a WP specific problem, use dependency injection instead of creating the object inside the controller

Comment: How can I use DI on a WP controller? Shall I create the container myself?

Comment: I don't know, the code that registers and creates the `WP_REST_My_Controller` instance or tells the API about it has not been included in the question. TLDR don't create objects inside your controller object, create them outside the object and hand/pass it to them the same way you would any other object

Comment: The pattern follows the [WP documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/controller-classes/) on extending its REST API. I've also added how the controller routes are registered through my plugin.

Comment: I could move the dependency outside the controller class, but it's still not clear to me how I could hook it up in my tests.

Comment: So in `rest_api_init` you have a hook with the class, where you have access to the object, you can set it there, or use a filter

Comment: Hmm I think I'm getting it but I'm not quite there yet. I have updated the example with the dependency passed during the `rest_api_init` hook, to ensure I am on the same page.

Comment: How could I "re-hook" that in my test class? Can I "overwrite" it  somehow in my `setUp()` method using a stub client?

Comment: filters! But have you considered that this is not a unit test but an integration test? Your test isn't even touching or creating your controller object